# I2C connection to MS5637 baro sensor using wiringI2CPi

Tags: i2c, wiringpi, pi-1

I am trying to write some code to connect and drag data across I2C using the [Wiring Pi](http://wiringpi.com/reference/i2c-library/) library, I'm at the stage where any data would be good but this is a link to the sensor's datasheet I'm trying to get data from
[MS5637-02BA03 Data Sheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=MS5637-02BA03&DocType=Data%20Sheet&DocLang=English/).

I believe I have wired everything up correctly and my Raspberry Pi is detecting the device using `i2cdetect` on address `0x76` as shown below.

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --         
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --
```

My call to `wiringPiI2CSetup` seems to be getting called successfully, (returning a value of 3). But all subsequent write attempts are returning values of -1 with an error of 5 (IO Error).

Here is the code I am using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    int returnVal;
    int fd;

    fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x76);
    printf("%d\n", fd);
    returnVal = wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0xEC, 0x1E);
    if (returnVal == -1) printf("error - %d\n", errno);
    printf("%d\n", returnVal);
    returnVal = wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0xEC, 0xA0);
    printf("%d\n", returnVal);
    return 0;
}
```

The values I get in return are:

```
3 
error - 5
-1
-1
```

Page 9 of that data sheet seems to suggest that I need to write to the `0xEC` register to issue commands, which is what I am trying to do. It says:

> Each I2C communication message starts with the start condition and it is ended with the stop condition. The MS5637 address is 1110110x (write : x=0, read : x=1).

Am I reading this wrong or completely missing something?
I've used this baro sensor on an Arduino so I can confirm the sensor is in working order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a different interpretation of the datasheet.

The device has no registers, you just send commands.

For example

- to reset the device: send the single byte 0x1E
- to read PROM location 0: send the single byte 0xA0 and then read two bytes back